# Crossfilter Example doesn't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I have downloaded the CrossFilter example from the following link:

https://github.com/square/crossfilter/tree/gh-pages

and it seems not to work. The page loads, but the charts and the table does not.
Is there some library I have to install first, or anything else?
I have read the wiki and the readme file, but found no instructions on how to use the library or at least make the the example work.

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I found an example that does work, however only in Firefox...

https://github.com/zackham/crossfilter/tree/gh-pages

Could someone explain why does this version work, but the original doesn't?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most browsers enforce strict permissions for reading files out of the local file system via AJAX. So you need to load the example via a local web server e.g. Python's built-in server:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &
```

Once this is running, go to `http://localhost:8888/`.

Comment: Jason's answer is spot on. An alternative would be XAMPP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). But that might be more than you want if you're just looking for something simple. An additional alternative (that IMHO makes using crossfilter easier) would be dc.js (http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/). There's a few blog posts on getting started on d3noob.org. The first post is here http://www.d3noob.org/2013/07/introduction-to-dcjs.html

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a bit more clarification...

Make sure you've added `python` to your path environment variable.  Once you've downloaded a Crossfilter example (this [airline example](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) can be downloaded/forked [here](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/tree/gh-pages)), run a command line or terminal and CD into that directory.

And, if you're running `python 3`, use the following:

`python -m http.server 8888 &`